# CSS rotate animation translates the element

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm having trouble (again) understanding CSS animations- specifically this rotate animation. When you hover over the image it should start to rotate back-and-forth. It does this, but only after shifting over to the bottom left. I've been looking for similar questions but haven't found an answer as to why this happens or how to prevent it.

```css
img {

  position: absolute;

  top: 50%;

  left: 50%;

  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

img:hover {

  animation-name: freakout;

  animation-duration: .5s;

  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}

@keyframes freakout {

  0%, 100% {

    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);

    /* IE 9 */

    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

    transform: rotate(0deg);

  }

  50% {

    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);

    /* IE 9 */

    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

    transform: rotate(7deg);

  }

}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.swimwithamanatee.biz/normal_ian-symbol-trichechus-spp22_left.png" />
```

Comment: NEVERMIND! I just saw my "translate -50%" that I was missing in the animation.

Comment: Use prefix-free or autoprefixer so you don't have to code vendor prefixes (ex. -webkit)

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind this is that in img tag Transform property uses Translate function so as to align the image to center but the moment you hover over the image the Transform property changes to Rotate property resulting in shifting of position while hovering over the image.I changed the code ,This will work.

```css
   img {

  position: absolute;

  top: 50%;

  left: 50%;

  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

img:hover {

  animation-name: freakout;

  animation-duration: .5s;

  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}

@keyframes freakout {

  0%, 100% {

    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg)translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* IE 9 */

    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

    transform: rotate(0deg)translate(-50%, -50%);

  }

  50% {

    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg)translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* IE 9 */

    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg)translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

    transform: rotate(7deg)translate(-50%, -50%);

  }

}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.swimwithamanatee.biz/normal_ian-symbol-trichechus-spp22_left.png" />
```